# How can I set the height of my container with jscrollpane?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have a table on my page and I would like to use jscrollpane to put scrollbars around it. I gave the table a width of 40rem (400px) and a height of 20rem. But when jscrollpane runs it creates a jspContainer with a height of 400px:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 1062px;" 
   scroll-pane 
   jspScrollable">             
   <div class="jspContainer" 
   style="width: 1062px; height: 400px;">
      <div class="jspPane" 
      style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1062px;">
         <table class="form grid" style="width: 40rem; height: 20rem;">
```

Here's my CSS.

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 40rem;
    height: 2rem;
    overflow: auto;
}
.jspContainer
{
    width: 40rem;
    height: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make it not create this large 400px pane.

Note here's how I call the plugin:

```
app.directive('myScrollpane', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass('scroll-pane');
            element.jScrollPane();  
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change css of scrollpane like this for example:

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem; //change the height of what you want
    overflow: auto;
}
.jspContainer
{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can change your height inside css like you want, 200px, 400px what you want

Comment: But I already did change it and it does not seem to make any difference. It still overrides it with: style="width: 1062px; height: 400px;"  That style information is what jscrollpane added.